# GSAP CDN not working in javascript or html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I am trying to animate some text by following a youtube video made by a guy named Gary Simon using GSAP.

I followed his instructions to the letter but nothing is moving. All he did was copy and paste the CDN for GSAP and CSSRulePlugin and I did the same but after telling my border to scale from 0 to 1 nothing happens. I slowed the video down to 0.5 to make sure I copied everything exactly but I can't find what I did wrong or if there is an extra step.

I tried typing npm install gsap and importing it but still nothing.

here is what I have in html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>GSAP stuff</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Look at me, I'm a bunch of letters...</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
    <script src='https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/tweenjs.min.js'></script>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/CSSRulePlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";
      import { CSSRulePlugin } from "gsap/dist/CSSRulePlugin";

      gsap.registerPlugin(CSSRulePlugin);

      const content = CSSRulePlugin.getRule('.content:before')
      const h1 = document.querySelector('h1') 
      const p = document.querySelector('p') 
      const tl = gsap.timeline() 

      tl.from(content, {cssRule: {scaleX:0}})
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS stuff...

```
*
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html,
body
{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: larger;
  color: white;
}

canvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 50vw;
  line-height: 5%;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  gap:5em;
  padding-top: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

.content:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Everything had been working the same as the video tutorial but GSAP doesn't work for me. Could there be something with the CDN?

Thank you please.

Comment: For detailed information related to loading GSAP correctly, look at [the GSAP install page](http://greensock.com/install).

Comment: That is the page I was using to try to use GSAP. It wasn't working because the video tutorial I was following was telling me to use the CSSRulePlugin. Once I took that out of my code, it worked. Thank you though, I will continue to use that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three lines are for nodejs, we can't directly put them in browsers

```js
import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";
import { CSSRulePlugin } from "gsap/dist/CSSRulePlugin";
gsap.registerPlugin(CSSRulePlugin);
```

After removing those lines, make sure to include this (as you already did)

```js
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

That's enough (usually we include it in head tag)

Also, if you only want to scale an element, you don't need CssRulePlugin and timeline.

just add

```js
gsap.from('.content', {scaleX: 0})
```

should work

Comment: I think it was just the CSSRule Plugin that isn't working because once i used the code you gave me it seemed to work.

The scaling was just the first step in the animation in the guy's video. We are trying to set a delay and other properties. The guy in the video says that the reason we need to use the css plugin is because "it lets us gain access to the transform scale element which is in a pseudoselector, '.content:before' ". He is using version 3.6.1 though, so does this mean that with version 3.7.1 of GSAP that what he said no longer applies?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: @MacAntonio Gary is a cool guy, if you need to animate pseudo element, CssRulePlugin is required indeed.
GSAP has a great docs, you can have a look(https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/CSSRulePlugin)

Comment: In most cases you can avoid the need for CSSRulePlugin by animating CSS variables instead as the docs for the CSSRulePlugin say.